# How can I change ViewController in non-viewController class in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, option-type

I'm using ble in app. when I tapped a button which start ble, BluetoothController class is work. It works good but when the process is come in to connect device, I want to show devices which can connect.
So I make a new ViewController which contain tableview. And a device is founded, call that ViewController. But when call that class, I got 'unwrapping an Optional value' error. I know when the error is occurred. But I don't know why and where is nil.

At first in BluetoothController, I got presentedView. Because it is not ViewController.

```
var topController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.rootViewController!
            if topController.presentedViewController != nil
            {
                topController = topController.presentedViewController!
            }
            topController.show(bv!, sender: nil)
```

The error is occurred ViewController which contain tableview.

```
BleAlertTableView.dataSource = self
```

I think AlertViewController(contain tableview) is not matter. I think topController and a method which change ViewController can be matter.

Comment: Is the problem is in the `self`? when you execute `print("\(self)")`  what do you get?

Comment: Deallocating could be the problem. Are you sure that you are holding the strong reference for it long enough?

Comment: @VictorSanchez I got BluetoothAlertViewController. that is right. But I got BleAlertTableView is nil. I don't know why this is nil.